# Finding SpriteRenderer of specific Child Gameobject

Tags: unity, c#, sprites

So i'm trying to work on my Equipment System to also change the appearance of the sprites on my Character once i change the equipped item. My animations are setup in limbs so all i would have to do (i think?) is change the actual sprite of the specific limb skin i want to change (e.g. The Shoes), since the animation should still work independent of what the sprite is. However the problem i'm having is that my equipment manager is on a seperate gameobject than the character is and i don't seem to be able to find the SpriteRenderer components (Null pointer reference). My current function looks like this:
Obviously the commented parts are irrelevant for my question, and i will eventually make the gameobject search more specific to which item piece i'm equipping. For clarification, the Equipment Manager is on my GameManager object and the sprites are on the [Player Screenshot](http://www.prntscr.com/jdwkq3) Object and its' children.

```
public void EquipItem(Equipment newItem)
{
    //int slotIndex = (int)newItem.equipSlot;
    //Equipment oldItem = null;

    SpriteRenderer targetSR;

    //if(currentEquipment[slotIndex] != null)
    //{
    //    oldItem = currentEquipment[slotIndex];
    //    inventory.AddItem(oldItem);
    //}

    //if (onEquipmentChanged != null)
    //{
    //    onEquipmentChanged.Invoke(newItem, oldItem);
    //}
    //currentEquipment[slotIndex] = newItem;


    targetSR = GameObject.Find("Mage5/Hip/Body/Hand_L").GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    targetSR.sprite = newItem.icon;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very slow method and unreliable in case you misspell some naming. Or just rename something. Use references to your `SpriteRenderer`s and simply use them when you need. For example place this in your character code.

```
[SerializeField] private BodyPartsSpriteRenderers _bodyPartsSpriteRenderers;

// Use example
private void Start()
{
    this._bodyPartsSpriteRenderers._Head.sprite = // Some head sprite
}

[System.Serializable]
public class BodyPartsSpriteRenderers
{
    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _head;
    public SpriteRenderer _Head     { get { return this._head; } }

    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _leftArm;
    public SpriteRenderer _LeftArm  { get { return this._leftArm; } }

    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _rightArm;
    public SpriteRenderer _RightArm { get { return this._rightArm; } }

    [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer _legs;
    public SpriteRenderer _Legs     { get { return this._legs; } }
}
```

Specific for your case:

```
public void EquipItem(Equipment newItem)
{
    switch (newItem._BodyPart) {.........
        case BodyPart.Legs:

            this._bodyPartsSpriteRenderers._Legs.sprite = newItem.icon;

        break;
    ..... }
}
```

Don't forget to assign them in  the inspector or you will get `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Thanks alot! Switch-Case definitely makes sense here aswell, works exactly as i wanted it to :)

Answer (score 0):

If your character have only on SpriteRenderer Component you can try something like

```
//Player is the root of your player gameobject
TargetSR = Player.GetcomponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();
TargetSR.sprite = newIcon;
```

Comment: The problem is that my Player Gameobject has a hierarchy of children which each have a spriterenderer (as seen in the screenshot, for example Hand_L and Hand_R both have a spriterenderer)